# Is it possible to add a video inside a popover?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to add a short video inside one of my popovers. I have tried the following:

```
    let htmlString = `
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <video class="embed-responsive-item" src="..." loop muted></video>
    </div>
    `;

    $('#popover').popover({
      trigger: 'manual',
      html: true,
      content: htmlString
    });
```

However, when activating this popover, the video element does not appear in the DOM. Using dev tools i can only see the videos container `<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Set `sanitize: false` for the popover and give the container of the video a `width` or `min-width`. You should propable also listen [popover events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/popovers/) if you want your video to start/stop playing on show/hide.

```
let html1 = `
    <div style="min-width: 300px;">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <video class="embed-responsive-item" src=".../...mp4" loop muted></video>
      </div>
    </div>
    `;

    $('#popover').popover({
      trigger: 'manual',
      html: true,
      sanitize: false,
      content: html1
    });
```